# Any canonical information on what happened to the Borg after "Endgame" episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg, star-trek-eu

[Memory Alpha's article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Endgame_%28episode%29) on Star Trek: Voyager "Endgame" episode states (*Continuity and Trivia*):

> Although dealt a crippling blow, it is unclear if the Borg have been defeated once and for all, as the pathogen may not have had enough time to spread (Michael Okuda claims, in the Star Trek: First Contact Special Edition DVD, that they weren't). Chronologically, though, this episode marks the final appearance of the Borg, although they went on to make an appearance on ENT: "Regeneration".

Is there any canonical information, beside above, on what happened later to the Borg? Or are we all left with just the mere speculations? Are there any non-canonical works, that deal with this?

Note, that I'm asking about chronological *after*, not about any work, that was written or created later than "Endgame" episode (like in Enterprise serie example).

Comment: AFAIK, there are no canon sources that mention the Borg after Endgame. There's the odd interview that relates to the "*possible future*", but none of them are considered canon sources.

Comment: This can be a good answer, Richard, if no one is to provide something more.

Comment: As far as the Expanded Universe books are concerned, there's tons of info about the future of the Borg, they invade the Alpha Quadrant, make Janeway their queen, re-assimilate Seven of Nine, etc etc. A good deal of this is self-contradictory and down to the individual writer to decide their own canon; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_history

Comment: That's the problem with the expanded Trek Universe.  It all contradicts one another.  At least with the Star Wars expanded universe (before they became the "Legends"), they tried to keep things relatively uniform and in sync.

Comment: a good source of expanded trek lore is star trek online. the borg are still around, however, the federation has the tech to actually fight on equal footing. in the game a taskforce in created between all of the races in startrek universe to actively fight the borg, stop their expansion, as well as actively hurt them in their home quadrant. while they regularly invade fed space, they are only a minor threat now, as the primary threat to the fed are the iconians.

Comment: I assume that "Canon" would preclude any of the post-DS9/Voy novels. Otherwise, the the Destiny trilogy contains a lot of details of the future history of the Borg.

Comment: Spoiler warning: don't read up about the book if you intend to actually read it.

Comment: I have to agree with @Richard, and in fact the only reason I haven't written that answer is that he should :-) Chronologically, Star Trek canon ends at the end of "Endgame", and seems unlikely to ever be extended in the "prime" timeline.

Comment: @UncleMikey - I'm happy for you to write it up.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, it does end a little later, and I'll note that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Canonically speaking, the chronology of the "prime" timeline of the *Star Trek* universe ends either with *Star Trek: Nemesis*, or perhaps with the destruction of Romulus by the Hobus Supernova in *Star Trek* (2009). Both of these are set after the return of *Voyager*.

Since neither of these stories mention the Borg at all, that I can recall, the only possible answer is: No. There is no **canonical** information on what happened to the Borg after "Endgame".

Pocket's novels set after the end of the series provide one possible answer (including a fairly epic crossover between TNG, VGR, and DS9 casts). This arc eventually resolves both the origin and the fate of the Borg, once and for all. It's important to remember, however, that the Star Trek EU has never been remotely canon, and future writers both of novels[*] and of possible movies and television series are free to ignore them entirely.

*Star Trek: Online* has a different, quite contradictory, possible answer which preserves the Borg as a threat (albeit a very different and evolving one) well into the 2400s. STO, however, is also not canon.

At this writing, there are no known plans to extend the "prime" timeline further forward in a canon medium (that is, television series or movie produced by Paramount). It is therefore very likely that no canonical answer will ever be known.

[*] Pocket **has** been making some effort in recent years to harmonize continuity within their novels--efforts that used to be actively stymied by Paramount's monitors and now seem to be permitted on the understanding that nothing Pocket does is binding on Paramount.

---

In early 2020, *Star Trek: Picard* finally extended the canonical timeline as far as the year 2399, 14 years after the supernova that destroyed the Romulan homeworlds. While this series did include, as one of its locations, a "broken" Borg cube known as The Artifact, we still have little additional information about what happened to the Borg as a whole.

We do know that the Borg were still an active threat as late as the 2380s, and that this particular cube attempted to assimilate a ship that was carrying Tal Shiar agents, including at least some Zhat Vash initiates. As a result of assimilating the Zhat Vash in particular, and coming into contact with The Admonition, that cube basically suffered the Borg equivalent of colony collapse disorder, allowing the Romulans to capture it.

Since then, the Romulans have mined the cube for technological secrets, while a Reclamation Project led by Hugh (formerly Third of Five) attempted to de-assimilate the former members of that cube's collective, with some success.

The fate and activities of the Borg Collective, beyond that one cube, are still unknown.

Comment: There's also the graphic novel *Star Trek: Countdown* which was the "official movie prequel" to *Star Trek* (2009), and was written by the script-writers of that movie (Roberto Orci and Alex Kurtzman). There's no information on the current state of the Borg, but at an "advanced military facility whose existence is known only to the Romulan High Command", Romulan researchers had "retrofitted Borg technology and applied it to Romulan designs", including "self-repairing nanotechnology" (used on Nero's ship), so that at least tells us Borg technology was being used by Alpha Quadrant civilizations.

Comment: What is the name of the crossover novel series you mentioned? Sounds interesting

Comment: That would be the Destiny Trilogy.

Comment: We appear to be in the process of learning more about this very subject as part of _Star Trek: Picard_. When S1 is complete, I will try to remember to come back and update this answer!

Comment: This has now been updated with what we know from Picard, Season 1.

Answer (score 0):

according to the "star trek destiny" trilogy novel the borg will be defeated.. after the crippling blow voyager dealt to the borg they saw the federation as a threat that could no longer be tolerated.. after they attack the federation with a fleet of 7600 borg ships, but somebody found one of the cealiar , they discover that borg nanoprobes are a corrupted version of cealiar catoms and after a lot of struggles the woman, erika hernandez manages to enter a probe and plugs into it, all the borg got absorbed and changed into cealiar , and the borg as we knew it was no more

Comment: The Destiny Trilogy is not part of Star Trek "canon" seeing as it was not published by Paramount. It is an epic crossover, yes, but doesn't satisfy the parameters of the question.

Comment: @malachi1990 - Note that the OP has also asked for "***any non-canonical works***" as well.

Comment: While your answer does somehow answer my question, its quality is very poor. I had really hard times reading it and trying to understand, what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Richard Ah, missed that last part of the question.